# Making JDialog shift colors

Tags: java, swing

I need help on making the JDialog shift colors. Also, how can I disable all components of the JFrame except for one button "STOP" that stops the execution of this color shifting button?
Do I have to use threads or swingworker? It would be really helpful if you could help me in details, and not just minimalistically. Thank you in advance!
If someone needs to see the whole code to help me, I can post it.

````
        Timer t;
        if(choiceTrueFalse==true){
            t = new Timer(Integer.valueOf(jTextField2.getText())*1000/speed, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                int i=0;  
                while(true){
                    i++;
                    if(i%2==0){
                    dialog.setBackground(c);
                    }
                    else{
                        dialog.setBackground(Color.white);
                    }           
                }
            }
        });```
````

Comment: One question per posting. Any code you post should be an [mre] that demonstrates one specific problem to keep the code simple and easy to understand. Since your title is about changing colors the is the question we can concentrate on. Disable buttons is a completely different topic.

Answer (score 1):

> I need help on making the JDialog shift colors.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to understand the structure of a JFrame, JDialog etc.

The "content pane" (which is just a JPanel by default) covers the dialog. So to change the background, you need to change the background of the content pane.

```
dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(...);
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I forgot the .getContentPane() method. But it still doesn't change it. And I don't know if it is because I'm using Thread.sleep, or for some other reason. I'm pasting the modified code below.
https://pastebin.com/Nw51GAxd

Comment: Post your [mre] in your question. We are not interested in your application. Only the code that demonstrates the stated problem. Note, if you are using a modal dialog, then the code after the setVisible() statement is not executed until the dialog is closed. Therefore the Timer needs to be started before the dialog is made visible.

Comment: @camrick I've put the setVisible() statement at the end of the loop, and it still does not work. Is using repaint() an option? Also, this might change the problem by a long shot, I have to make another button that stops the loop. So if I first program the stop button will it be easier to solve rather than making a blinking method first?

Comment: If the dialog isn't visible, then changing the background will do nothing. I have already given you the solution. I still don't see your [mre] so I can't help any further.

Comment: ```while(true){
                dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
                try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException ex){}
                dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(c);
                try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(InterruptedException ex){}
                dialog.setVisible(true);
                }```

This doesn't make the JPanel (JDialog) blink. Where should I put the .setVisible(true)? And I can paste the whole method to pastebin if you'd like. I introduced 2 threads(1 starts the blinking, the other stops it).

Comment: The code you posted does NOT compile. I can't copy/paste/compile and test. The problem is the structure of your code. I can't tell what your code is doing based on 10 lines of code. You have been asked 4 times for an [mre]. If you can't post one I can't help.